# While i am getting an error The system failed to create the file “/footer.php.lock” (as EUID: 1000, EGID: 1002 1002) Permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress

when i am trying to making any changes in file i am getting the permission error

> The system failed to create the file
>   “public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/footer.php.lock” (as
>   EUID: 1000, EGID: 1002 1002) because of the following error:
>   Permission denied

I have also tried with change the files permission to 777. but not worked 
Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your public_html folder user to current user.
Something like below

```
chown username public_html -R
```

This answer comes late, I think it might help someone.